# Which layout manager is suitable for not stretching text?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

Hi so I'm making a class scheduler for one of my software classes and I'm running into a problem when it comes to allowing the user to resize the window. Whenever the user resizes it the the layout of everything changes. Like for example when the user makes the window bigger the text moves to a different location in the window. How do I prevent that?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class FirstGUI extends JFrame {
private JTextArea textAreaMon;
private JTextArea textAreaTue;
private JTextArea textAreaWed;
private JTextArea textAreaThu;
private JTextArea textAreaFri;
private JTextArea description;
private Container pane;

public FirstGUI() {

    // create the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final Exam Scheduler");
    frame.setSize(900, 900);
    // closing frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);


    JButton openButton = new JButton("Open File");
    frame.add(openButton);


    // textField = new JTextField(20);
    textAreaMon = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textAreaTue = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textAreaWed = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textAreaThu = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textAreaFri = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    description = new JTextArea(5,20);

    textAreaMon.setEditable(false);
    textAreaTue.setEditable(false);
    textAreaWed.setEditable(false);
    textAreaThu.setEditable(false);
    textAreaFri.setEditable(false);
    description.setEditable(false);

    // frame.add(textField);
    frame.add(description);
    frame.add(textAreaMon);
    frame.add(textAreaTue);
    frame.add(textAreaWed);
    frame.add(textAreaThu);
    frame.add(textAreaFri);

    String gE1 = "Group Exam 1";
    String gE2 = "Group Exam 2";
    String gE3 = "Group Exam 3";
    String gE4 = "Group Exam 4";
    String gE5 = "Group Exam 5";
    String gE6 = "Group Exam 6";
    String gE7 = "Group Exam 7";
    String gE8 = "Group Exam 8";
    String gE9 = "Group Exam 9";


    textAreaMon.setText(
            "Monday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t" +  gE1 + " \n 10:15-12:15:\t" +        gE2 + " \n 12:45 - 2:45:\t\n 3:00 - 5:00:\t\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t" + gE3 + " \n 7:45 - 9:45:\t\n \n");
    textAreaTue.setText(
            "Tuesday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t\n 10:15-12:15 :\t" + gE4 + " \n 12:45 - 2:45:\t\n 3:00 - 5:00:\t\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t\n 7:45 - 9:45:\t\n \n");
    textAreaWed.setText(
            "Wednesday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t\n 10:15-12:15:\t\n 12:45 - 2:45 :\t" + gE5 + " \n 3:00 - 5:00:\t\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t\n 7:45 - 9:45:\t\n \n");
    textAreaThu.setText(
            "Thursday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t\n 10:15-12:15 :\t" + gE6 + " \n 12:45 - 2:45:\t\n 3:00 - 5:00:\t\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t" + gE7 + " \n 7:45 - 9:45:\t\n \n");
    textAreaFri.setText("Friday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t" + gE8 + " \n 10:15-12:15:\t\n 12:45 - 2:45:\t" + gE9);
    description.setText("Click the open button to import your .csv file into the program. Your schedule and times will be listed in the schedule below.");

     //frame.getContentPane().add(openButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // attach the fileOpener to the "Open" button
    openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            new InterfacePanel();
        }
    });

    // show it
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FirstGUI();
}
```

}

Comment: When I run your code, I don't see any stretched text when I resize the window.

Comment: Absolute layout does not allow you to stretch the text

Comment: `GridBagLayout` and `FlowLayout` come to find

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't word it right. Whenever the user resizes the window it changes the layout of everything. Like the words and button move to a different position than what I want. How do I prevent that?